# mysql select shows same wp_agent_adds.id not unique

Tags: mysql, select, unique

I need a query that shows each wp_agent_adds.id unique. In below query there are records that have more agent_target_countries per wp_agent_adds.id. For instance a wp_agent_adds.id has 3 agent_target_countries: BE, GB , NL. As result I get 3 records instead of only 1.

> How can I unique filter on wp_agent_adds.id in this query?

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT  t1.*, t2.*,
    t3.id as cid, t3.company_name, t3.city, t3.country          
    FROM wp_agent_adds AS t1
    INNER JOIN wp_agent_target_countries AS t2 ON t2.add_id = t1.id 
    INNER JOIN wp_agent_customer AS t3 ON t3.user_id = t1.user_id       
    WHERE t1.visible = 1    
    ORDER BY t1.date_added DESC
    ";
```

Result is:
id= 100 - target= BE, id= 100 - target= GB, id= 100 - target= NL

Comment: As per your query, it seems you are having multiple records for one key. so the join is giving you the 3 rows. if you do not want to use all the column then try to use name of particular column in the select statement and then use distinct.

OR

use group by t1.id

Comment: GROUP BY t1.id was indeed the correct option. Thanks.